# Relacionamento entre classes - (C# EntityFramework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Olá,

Possuo uma classe de Pessoa e uma Classe Endereco

Ex.

```
public class Pessoa
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    ...
        public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    }

public class Endereco
    {
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
...
    }
```

Quando vou executar o Update-Database do EntityFramework é gerada uma tabela de Endereço com relacionamento Um para Um, porém a ideia era que os campos de endereço fizessem parte da tabela de Pessoa sem relacionamento, isso é possível?

Ex. gostaria que a tabela de pessoa, ficasse com os campos **Id, Nome, Logradouro, Numero**.

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Você gerou `DbSet` para `Endereco`?

Comment: Não, por isso pensei que não iria gerar a tabela..

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa e pelo o que me pareceu não é possível popular os models da maneira como você deseja. Mas uma pergunta, por que você precisa que isso seja feito dessa maneira?

Comment: @Zignd  eh possível sim, de uma olhada na minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o EF está inferindo que existe alguma PK, por tanto não mantem a convenção para *ComplexTypes*, então como não postou o código completo da classe `Endereço` não sei dizer qual a propriedade que está causando isso, tenta colocar a configuração explicita para *ComplexType* de `Endereco`, sobrescreva o  método `OnModelCreating` de `DbContext` no seu context assim:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.ComplexType<Endereco>();
}
```

> Segue um link sobre **ComplexTypes**, olhe a seção **"*How to implement a Complex Type with Code First*"**  ele utiliza exatamente o exemplo de endereço, note que ele começa o artigo apresentando um relacionamento 1:1 e depois *desnormaliza* e utilza *[ComplexTypes](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations)*.

Answer (score 0):

Se relacionamento for uma pessoa tem um endereço fica assim:

```
 public class Pessoa
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    ...
        public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    }

    public class Endereco
        {
            public string Logradouro { get; set; }
            public string Numero { get; set; }
            public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

        }
```

Se relacionamento for uma pessoa tem muitos endereços vai ter que ficar assim :

```
public class Pessoa
        {

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Nome { get; set; }

            public virtual List<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }

        }

 public class Endereco
{

               public string Logradouro { get; set; }
                public string Numero { get; set; }
                public int IdPessoa //Chave estrangeira
                public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

}
```

isso vai do conceito de modelagem de dados 1:N chave primária do lado um vira chave estrangeira do lado muitos.ainda falta coisa pode dar uma olhada em mapeamento de entidades que você pode fazer via datanotation ou por fluent API recomendo dar uma olha por esse site http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx